# How to write a prolog rule that calculates the average salary?

Tags: prolog

I have this Database in Prolog:

```
family(person( john, cohen, date(17,may,1990), unemployed), person( lily, cohen, date(9,may,1990), unemployed),[ ] ).
family(person( john, armstrong, date(7,may,1988), unemployed), person( lily, armstrong, date(29,may,1961), unemployed), [ ] ).
family(person( eric, baily, date(7,may,1963), works( bbc, 2200)), person( grace, baily, date(9,may,1965), works( ntu, 1000)), [person( louie, baily, date(25,may,1983), unemployed) ] ).
family(person( eric, baily, date(7,may,1963), works( acc, 21200)), person( grace, baily, date(9,may,1965), works( ntnu, 12000)), [person( louie, baily, date(25,may,1983), unemployed) ] ).
family(person( eric, fox, date(27,may,1970), works( bbc, 25200)), person( grace, fox, date(9,may,1971), works( ntbu, 13000)), [person( louie, fox, date(5,may,1993), unemployed) ] ).
husband(X) :- family(X, _, _).
wife(X) :- family(_, X, _).
child(X) :- family(_, _, Children), member(X, Children).
salary(person(_, _, _, works(_, S)), S).
salary(person(_, _, _, unemployed), 0).
```

The format is:
family(husband,wife,[children]).
Each person in the family has a name, family name, date of birth, work and salary.

I have an assignment that requires me to write the following rules:

1) Write a prolog rule 'totalIncome/2' to compute the total income of a family.

2) Write a prolog query to print total income of each family.

I was able to get the salaries for the husbands in a list and the salaries of the wives in another list.

```
salaries(L) :- findall(X,family(person(_,_,_,works(_,X)),_,_),L).
salaries(L2) :- findall(X,family(_,person(_,_,_,works(_,X)),_),L2).
```

I can't seem to get my head around it so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use the [**`aggregate`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) library.

Comment: But perhaps it makes more sense to first calculate the sum of a list of values, how would you implement a `sum/2` predicate such that `sum([1,4,2,5], 12).`?

Comment: @MichaelRahmeh: well you need a basecase as well `sum([], 0)`. but indeed, the recursive part is correct.

Comment: Now with `findall/3` you can obtain *all* incoms: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3

Comment: @MichaelRahmeh: that is covered in the `findall/3` as well, you can first unify with a specific family, then find the salaries for these persons, and then use the `sum` to add these up.

Comment: @MichaelRahmeh: hmm... Yes, I think I misunderstood that. Well you have a family, that family has persons, so you can construct a list for a `family(H, W, [C1, C2, C3])` to `[H, W, C1, C2, C3]` (of course taking into account that there can be zero, one, etc. `C`s), then mapping these persons to the salary, and `sum`ming these up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking in a wring direction I think... You shouldn't be computong salries for different families, e.g wives salaries but the salary for a family, here is my implementation:

```
add(X,Y,Sum):- Sum is X+Y.
sum(Xs,Sum):- foldl(add,Xs,0,Sum).

totalIncome(family(X,Y,T), Income):- 
         family(X,Y,T),maplist(getSalary,[X,Y|T], L), sum(L,Income).

getSalary(person(_,_,_,works(_,X)), X).
getSalary(person(_,_,_,unemployed), 0).
```

Example:

```
?- totalIncome(X,P).
X = family(person(john, cohen, date(17, may, 1990), unemployed), person(lily, cohen, date(9, may, 1990), unemployed), []),
P = 0 ;
X = family(person(john, armstrong, date(7, may, 1988), unemployed), person(lily, armstrong, date(29, may, 1961), unemployed), []),
P = 0 ;
X = family(person(eric, baily, date(7, may, 1963), works(bbc, 2200)), person(grace, baily, date(9, may, 1965), works(ntu, 1000)), [person(louie, baily, date(25, may, 1983), unemployed)]),
P = 3200 ;
X = family(person(eric, baily, date(7, may, 1963), works(acc, 21200)), person(grace, baily, date(9, may, 1965), works(ntnu, 12000)), [person(louie, baily, date(25, may, 1983), unemployed)]),
P = 33200 ;
X = family(person(eric, fox, date(27, may, 1970), works(bbc, 25200)), person(grace, fox, date(9, may, 1971), works(ntbu, 13000)), [person(louie, fox, date(5, may, 1993), unemployed)]),
P = 38200 ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I want to get the salary of a specific family lets say family 1, is it possible ?

Comment: Yes just call totalIncome(family(...parameters of family 1...), S).

Comment: hey do you know how to separate the children income from their parents, i mean have two different incomes ?

Comment: Why not post another question... ??

Comment: oh yeah sorry, I will now. I have two questions, am I allowed to post them both ?

Comment: If they are highly related then yeah... else it would be better and more helpful to ask separately...

Comment: I posted my question, thanks for clearing things up!